# RStudio monthly time series data plot issue

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have a dataset of number of road accidents of each month from January 2014 to December 2019. I have read this data in Rstudio from a csv file that contained all the 72 datapoints in a single column using the code:

```
data<- read.csv("Accidents.csv", header=FALSE,sep=',')
```

Now I have turned this data into a timeseries object:

```
acctimeseries<-ts(data, frequency =12,start=c(2014,1))
```

Then as I print 'acctimeseries', it shows perfectly fine, from 2014 to 2019:
[image]

But when I plot it:

```
plot.ts(acctimeseries)
```

It continues after 2019 and goes to 2020, like this:

[image]

But I do not have any data point in 2020. So why is it continuing upto 2020? Also in the environment window in RStudio, it shows 'acctimeseries from 2014 to 2020:

[image]

I cannot understand how to resolve this.

Comment: It's not 2012, but Dec. 2019. The curve is not touching the vertical grid from 2020. Also, the time periods are taken as decimals where 2019.00 indicates Jan and 2019.917 indicates Dec. While showing this in environment, it rounds of the year. You can check this with time(acctimeseries)

Comment: @Mohanasundaram Okay, thanks. Is there anything I can do so that the point 2020 does not show on x-axis?